# Using the Python gnupg package, I am getting the error "Homedir ''C:/Users/...' needs read/write permissions"

Tags: python, gnupg, pgp

I am running Windows 7 with Python version 3.6.1 in Anaconda. I installed the python package gnupg, using `pip install gnupg`.

I downloaded the gnupg Windows executable 2.1.23  from ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/.

When I run the code with either of the two lines below it fails with the following error.

```
import gnupg

gpg = gnupg.GPG(binary='C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe',
               homedir='C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/SFTP Connection')

# gpg = gnupg.GPG(binary='C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe')
```

However when I run the Python code with either of the two lines it fails.

```
import gnupg
# gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG')
gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gnupg\_meta.py in _homedir_setter(self, directory)
    434                 assert _util._has_readwrite(hd), \
--> 435                     "Homedir '%s' needs read/write permissions" % hd
    436             except AssertionError as ae:

AssertionError: Homedir ''C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/SFTP Connection'' needs read/write permissions

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ae272cb064fb> in <module>()
      1 gpg = gnupg.GPG(binary='C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe',
----> 2                homedir='C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/SFTP Connection')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gnupg\gnupg.py in __init__(self, binary, homedir, verbose, use_agent, keyring, secring, ignore_homedir_permissions, options)
    123             verbose=verbose,
    124             use_agent=use_agent,
--> 125             ignore_homedir_permissions=ignore_homedir_permissions,
    126         )
    127 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gnupg\_meta.py in __init__(self, binary, home, keyring, secring, use_agent, default_preference_list, ignore_homedir_permissions, verbose, options)
    181         self.ignore_homedir_permissions = ignore_homedir_permissions
    182         self.binary  = _util._find_binary(binary)
--> 183         self.homedir = os.path.expanduser(home) if home else _util._conf
    184         pub = _parsers._fix_unsafe(keyring) if keyring else 'pubring.gpg'
    185         sec = _parsers._fix_unsafe(secring) if secring else 'secring.gpg'

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gnupg\_util.py in __set__(self, obj, value)
    763             self.fset(obj, value)
    764         else:
--> 765             getattr(obj, self.fset.__name__)(value)
    766 
    767     def __delete__(self, obj):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gnupg\_meta.py in _homedir_setter(self, directory)
    438                 log.debug("GPGBase.homedir.setter(): %s" % msg)
    439                 log.debug(str(ae))
--> 440                 raise RuntimeError(str(ae))
    441             else:
    442                 log.info("Setting homedir to '%s'" % hd)

RuntimeError: Homedir ''C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/SFTP Connection'' needs read/write permissions
```

I've ran the following two commands and verified the folder has read and write access.

```
>>> os.access('C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/SFTP Connection', os.W_OK)
True
>>> os.access('C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/SFTP Connection', os.R_OK)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to the new permissions error, I guess it is actually a bug of gnupg, I [have submitted a patch](https://github.com/isislovecruft/python-gnupg/pull/215).

Comment: thanks for filling the issue. I thought it was something wrong with my system.

Comment: I see you submitted the commit 10 hours ago and it still hasn't been updated. Have commits you submitted before taken this long as well?

Comment: you could apply the patch or modify the file in question on your own machine to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

The GnuPG home directory is where GnuPG stores it's keyrings and information. You cannot use this configuration variable to determine where the Python module searches for the binary. In fact, this *never* should be set to the place the binary is stored (and also should never be in your program files directory, anyway).

Instead, add the directory to your `%PATH` environment variable or use the [`binary`](https://pythonhosted.org/gnupg/gnupg.html#gnupg-module) variable, which should contain the absolute path of the binary:

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(binary='C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe')
```

From the [Python module's documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/gnupg/gnupg.html#gnupg-module):

> `binary` (`str`) – Name for GnuPG binary executable. If the absolute path is not given, the environment variable `$PATH` is searched for the executable and checked that the real uid/gid of the user has sufficient permissions.
>
> `homedir` (`str`) – Full pathname to directory containing the public and private keyrings. Default is whatever GnuPG defaults to.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I get a different error after specifying the correct binary file saying the directory I am running the program with the keys `needs read/write permissions`. I verified it has both though.